# When will AWS RDS Freeable Memory be recycled?

Tags: amazon-rds

The production environment uses AWS RDS (Mysql), RDS Freeable memory has been declining, as picture 1 shown, the RDS instance type is db.m3.xlarge, when can Freeable memory be recycled? Or it will always drop, drop to 0?

[image: picture 1]

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation available at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.UsingMetrics, freeable memory is the RAM in use by your instance. If you are running out of freeable memory, you should upgrade your instance.

> Freeable Memory – How much RAM is available on the DB instance, in megabytes. The red line in the Monitoring tab metrics is marked at 75% for CPU, Memory and Storage Metrics. If instance memory consumption frequently crosses that line, then this indicates that you should check your workload or upgrade your instance.

However, on your instance the available RAM is most likely not causing issues. There are recommendations for configuring RAM on the same article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.Performance.RAM.